# Canvas - How to draw hexagon, but vertex up and without rotate

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I need to draw hexagon but vertex has to go up. I created this using rotate method from canvas, but now I have to make it without rotating. I need hexagon path to be like this:

[image]

This is how my hexagon path look like now:

[image]

```js
let size = 21
let x = 70
let y = 60
let side = 0
   
path = new Path2D();
    
path.moveTo(x + size * Math.cos(0), y + size * Math.sin(0));

for (side; side < 7; side++) {
 path.lineTo(x + size * Math.cos(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6), y + size * Math.sin(side * 2 * Math.PI / 6));
}
```

Is there any way to make a path for this hexagon to be placed with vertex to up without using rotate method?

Comment: simply add angle when calculate vertex.

Comment: I finally managed to do this using it like this
path.lineTo(x+Math.cos((side*(Math.PI*2)/6-(Math.PI*2)/4))*size,y+Math.sin((side*(Math.PI*2)/6-(Math.PI*2)/4))*size);

Answer (score 0):

This method not only gets you pentagons but will also draw you any polygon.

```js
function polygon(x, y, N, r, color) { //x&y are positions, N is side number, r is size, color is to fill

ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo (x + r * Math.cos(0), y + r *  Math.sin(0));

  for (var i = 1; i <= N; i += 1) {
    ctx.lineTo (x + r * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / N), y + r * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / N));
}
//Below draws the shape
ctx.strokeStyle = color;
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.save();
//Below fills the shape
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
}
```

You can take out the fill() part if you just want the outline, but if you strictly need a pentagon, just replace all instances of N with 5.